# Row layout with text within two icons

Tags: android, layout

I need a layout for a (list) row which contains two `ImageView` and one `TextView` (in the middle). Both images should be to the edges of the screen and the `TextView` is expected to fill the space between. My problem is, that the text can be set dynamically. Right now I'm working with a `TableLayout` and the attribute `android:stretchColumns`, but it could be that the text is longer then the available size, so both `ImageView` are moved out of the screen.

Can someone provide a layout for me, with is resistant for long textes ?

It should look like this:
[image: Visualisation of desired layout]

Comment: make your question picturize so that we can come to know the actual thing you are trying to implement.

Comment: OK. Solved the problem with the original TableLayout. Added 'android:ellipsize="marquee" android:singleLine="true" ' (even though `singleLine` is deprecated! - But inputType="text" blocked any click on this list item). Now it works! I would still be interested in a solution with the `RelativeLayout`. Thanks!

Comment: Would you please paste all the layout configuration? 10x

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with FILL_PARENT; check out the Layout Weight parameters.
You have to set the ImageViews with WRAP_CONTENT, the TextView with FILL_PARENT. Then apply some Layout Weight value (just use "1") to the TextView and see the magic work.

Edit: Example:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/add">
</ImageView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:text="as long as you wish">
</TextView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/add">
</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Another edit (Sorry, should read better the question):
If you have multiple rows and the row gets to wide for the screen because of other rows, you can set TableLayout.setColumnShrinkable() for that row.

Comment: Both ways don't have the desired effect... :( Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would try playing around with something like the XML below.  I haven't tried it, but its based on:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html;

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:src="@drawable/icon2"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image2"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seems to be the right way, but there' still a little problem: If i use this layout the icons used for the `ImageView` are way to big. How can I limit their width to the one of the `TextView` without editing the `.png` itself?!